# Error rounding 3 digits to 2 digits in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, rounding

```
var value1 = 1.325;
var value2 = 8.925;

console.log(value1.toFixed(2)); // my result: 1.32
console.log(value2.toFixed(2)); // my result: 8.93
```

value1 should be `1.33` but I am getting `1.32`.
value2 is getting rounded correct.

**EDIT/SOLUTION:**
This question is not a duplicate. (please see the comments).
The only working code for this question is:

```
function round(value, decimals) {
        return Number(Math.round(value+'e'+decimals)+'e-'+decimals);
}
```

Comment: Mike, let me know if I have done it in a mistake. This is an exact duplicate. JavaScript is like that.

Comment: @Praveen Kumar This isn't a duplicate.

Comment: @xoxox Sure? Okay... Lemme know I will open it.

Comment: @Mike Should I reopen it?

Comment: @Praveen Kumar Mike asked how to round correctly instead of truncating. The other question is about the flaw when two floats are added.

Comment: @PraveenKumar please reopen it.

Comment: @Mike Now I cannot reopen... Already I reopened and now it has been closed by others. Sorry Mike! `:(`

Comment: my soluion for that problem: `function round(value, decimals) { return Number(Math.round(value+'e'+decimals)+'e-'+decimals); }`

Comment: can anyone with the right authorization, remove the duplication "tag" and reopen the question, that I can add my correct answer to it. Thank you!